# AppImageLauncher stuck at 'Watching directories' when trying to run eDEX-UI AppImage

Tags: command-line, permissions, appimage

I recently installed eDEX-UI on my Ubuntu system using the AppImage format. However, when I attempted to run the AppImage from the terminal using the command sudo appimagelauncherd eDEX-UI-Linux-x86_64.AppImage, the AppImageLauncher seems to get stuck at the message "Watching directories:". It doesn't proceed any further and the application doesn't start.

I've confirmed that the AppImage file eDEX-UI-Linux-x86_64.AppImage is located in the directory I'm executing the command from. Additionally, I've checked that both the AppImage and AppImageLauncher have executable permissions.

I'm encountering this issue with other AppImages too. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem with AppImageLauncher getting stuck at "Watching directories:"? Are there any known solutions to this issue? I'm open to suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem so I can successfully run eDEX-UI using the AppImage. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Permission: `chmod +x eDEX-UI-Linux-x86_64.AppImage`

Running:

```
$ sudo appimagelauncherd  eDEX-UI-Linux-x86_64.AppImage
Searching for existing AppImages
Watching directories:
```

Comment: The appimage likely is supposed to be run as `/path/to/file/eDEX-UI-Linux-x86_64.AppImage' or `./eDEX-UI-Linux-x86_64.AppImage' if the appimage is in your current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ran appimage in the terminal and it said:

```
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run. 
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
```

Then I installed FUSE again with the help of [this](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE) GitHub page and  the problem was solved.